# Whether to store userId in localStorage or fetch it from server by decoding jwt token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern

I am absolutely confused that whether should I store the userId in localStorage and fetch it from localStorage whenever i have to use it or I have seen many people storing their userId in jwt token and fetching it from server by decoding it. Which is the right approach or is there any other better way?

```
     const userId = localStorage.getItem("highfitid")

      axios.post("http://localhost:6007/getusercart",{
       method:"GET",
       headers:{'Content-Type':"application/json"},
       userId
      } ).then((data) =>{
        setCartproduct(data.data)
    ///  console.log(data, 'cart')
      })
  
     }, [userId])
```

Comment: what does the code in the question have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your use case. Can you be more specific?

If you're looking for ways to store user Id, I'd advise you not to store them in  `localStorage` or any form of browser storage as it is not secure.
Encrypting the user Id in a JWT and decrypting it in a server makes more sense.

Comment: in this example i,am pushing user selected item into cart array and i want to make sure that i store it along with userid  so that it get easy to find cart items of user by his userid or id of that user but here i have first stored userid in localstorage and then i,am fetching it from there to post user cart item along with its userid but i feel that its not the right way to do it

Comment: @webdevShubhamKumar I don't know if you're using any kind of state management library in your app like Redux. I'd rather store user Ids in the app's state than in any form of browser storage

Comment: yes i,am using redux toolkit but i dont know how can i do it using redux can you explain it little bit that how i can store user id in my redux state

Comment: @webdevShubhamKumar It's difficult to explain it here. There are tons of online tutorials about react and redux. you can look it up

Comment: will it be called user authentication